# error importing module you created (Python)

Tags: python, import, module

I created module that have tree functions and when I am trying to import that module I have red line under the module name and the error says "No module named data" and the file is in the same path as the file I am trying to import to. but the functions are working but it's causing bugs in my program,
Someone know how do I fix that problem?.

Comment: what have you tried ?

Comment: I tried to install the that module but it's did not working

Comment: how did you installed it?

Comment: Does, `from data import func1, func2, func3` work? where func1, func2, func3 are the three functions

Comment: its work like before but there still a red line that says that this module doesn't exsist